# Using perl arrays to compare file names to find matching mp3 and m4a file types

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, filenames

I've populated an array with all files with the file extension of `mp3` and a separate array with all `m4a` files as listed below

```
my @mp3filesarray = grep ( -f ,<*.mp3>);
my @m4afilesarray = grep ( -f ,<*.m4a>);
```

What I would like to do is compare the file names of the arrays to see if there is a match or partial match and, if there is, copy both the mp3 file and the m4a file to a new sub directory so that I may review the files to determine which file I want to keep. I am sure that I need to use a regex for this but am not sure how to this. I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd approach this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Copy qw(move);

my %seen;
while ( my $file = glob '*.{mp3,m4a}' )
{
    ++$seen{ substr($file, 0, length() - 4) };
}

for my $dupe ( grep { $seen{$_} > 1 } keys %seen )
{
    make_path($dupe);
    move("$dupe.$_", "$dupe/$dupe.$_" for (qw(mp3 m4a)); # Change / to \ if you're on Windows
}
```

I start by globbing all files ending in m4a or mp3, then strip it down to the basename without an extension and hash it. Then I loop over any duplicates and move them into their own folder.

A regular expression would be overkill, since the glob expansion syntax is much more restrictive than a regular expression.

This approach only finds duplicates where the only difference is the file extension, however. To do fuzzy matching you'd need a different technique than the O(n) hashing strategy I used.

---

The first `while` loop could also be written using `File::Basename::fileparse()`, like so:

```
while (my $file = glob '*.{mp3,m4a}')
{
    my $name = fileparse($file, qr/ [.] [^.]* \z/x);
    ++$seen{$name};
}
```

Comment: I would add that you might want to use [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) to get just the filename, instead of `substr()`

Comment: @RobK I used File::Basename when I started writing it, but I nixed it after thinking the glob pattern will be restrictive enough that a solution using `substr()` won't have edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is quite expensive - in order to look for partial matches, you need to compare each filename with each *other* filename. Presumably you don't want to compare the mp3 list with each other, which makes it a *little* easier.

I'd go with a `foreach` loop:

```
my %files;

foreach my $file ( glob ( '*.mp3 *.m4a' ) {
    my ( $name, $type ) = ( $file =~ m/(\w+)\.(m[4p][a3])/ );
    $files{$type}{$name}++;
}

foreach my $mp3_file ( keys %{ $files{'mp3'} } ) {
    if ( $files{'m4a'} ) { print "Dupe detected: mp3_file\n"; next; }
    foreach my $m4a_file ( keys %{ $files{'m4a'} } ) {
        if ( $mp3_file =~ m/\Q$m4a_file/ ) { print "Partial match $mp3_file $m4a_file\n"; }
        if ( $m4a_file =~ m/\Q$mp3_file/ ) { print "Partial match $m4a_file $mp3_file\n"; }
    }
}
```

Something like that - you're doing a straight substring comparison on the file name - without extension. You'll want to do the same with the m4a to mp3 compare. (You could simplify a bit if you're prepared to compare each file with each file independent of extension, but you also increase the number of comparisons... and of course, you're guaranteed at least one duplicate :))

Comment: Why do you mention `map`?

Comment: Er. Good point. I shall edit. I transpose mentally transpose `map` and `grep` because they're in many ways the same function.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont have any numbers in file (like 1.mp3 or a12b.m4a) then this would work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

system("sudo mkdir review");

my (@spmp3,@spm4a);
my @mp3file=`ls | grep mp3`;
my @m4afile=`ls | grep m4a`;


for (my $i=0; $i<=$#mp3file; $i++)
{
  @spmp3 = split (/\./, $mp3file[$i]);
}

for (my $j=0; $j<=$#m4afile; $j++)
{
  push (@spm4a,  split (/\./, $m4afile[$j]));
}

for (my $k=0; $k<=$#mp3file; $k=$k+2)
{
  for (my $l=0; $l<=$#m4afile; $l=$l+2)
  {
    if ( $spmp3[$k] eq  $spm4a[$l] )
    {
      system(" mv $spmp3[$k].mp3 $spm4a[$k].m4a ./review");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `system` to call `mkdir`, which Perl provides a builtin for. The `system("mv ...` line also won't work if the filenames contain metacharacters. You could use the list form of `system` to avoid having to escape them, but there's no need to use anything that isn't provided by core Perl already.